# Temperature Programmed Disorption

Tags: surface-chemistry

[image]

For second part of the question I'm wondering if the peaks on the right denote the chemisorbed layer, while the peaks on the left denote the physisorbed layers. Since chemisorption results in a stronger covalent bond, the energy to remove adsorbates than the physisorbed layers

Comment: What is plotted on the vertical scale ? It is 1000 or 2000 what ? What units ?

Comment: The Y axis is rate